# Did Boris Pavlovich Belousov die in 1970 or 1976?

Tags: military, 20th-century, soviet-union, death

I'm working on a paper about the [Belousov-Zhabotinsky-reaction](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26872038_B_P_Belousov_and_his_reaction) (a chemical oscillator).

I included some information about the history of oscillation reaction, in particular about [Boris Pavlovich Belousov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boris_Pavlovich_Belousov) and [Anatol Markovich Zhabotinskii](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatol_Zhabotinsky).

Boris Belousov was the first to discover the Belousov-Zhabotinsky-reaction (BZ-reaction), whilst Zhabotinsky later continued Belousovs research.

My problem now is the year that Boris Belousov died. I have a few contradicting sources. The year is 1970 or 1976.

Some sources that say 1970: Wikipedia, [Nature](https://www.nature.com/articles/4551053a#article-info), [Handbook on the Physics and Chemistry of Rare Earths](https://books.google.nl/books?id=_Ro3Fqtz4xgC&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=boris%20pavlovich%20belousov%20year%20of%20death&source=bl&ots=kYJljSB-a1&sig=ACfU3U0qnuJFs_nH4Tx3MHOyh6kFI3yrtw&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirqNy1re3pAhULwKQKHd2uBsYQ6AEwBnoECBIQAQ#v=onepage&q=boris%20pavlovich%20belousov%20year%20of%20death&f=false).

Source that says 1976: [Journal of Biosciences](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/26872038_B_P_Belousov_and_his_reaction). 
*This source does not have references on where the year 1976 came from.*

Do you agree that I should use 1970, because that is what most sources say? Or is it more plausible that it is 1976, because that source has a DOI? But on the other hand, the second source did not include references on the year of death..

Comment: http://hsm.stackexchange.com

Comment: How is the discoverer of chemical oscillators related to anything military?

Comment: In such questions, Russian Wikipedia can be trusted: he dies on June 12, 1970.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo thanks for pointing that SE out, I didn't about that one. Belousov discovered his reaction during work/research for the Russian military. To be honest, when posting this question I didn't really have an idea what tags I should use for it, so when I came across 'military' I decided just to add it because of the above reason.

Comment: @Alex is that a rule of thumb for Russian-/ Soviet-related questions?

Comment: @ralphsmit: No. But this is a rule of thumb for formal biographical data of famous Russians.

Comment: Searched for him on Russian internet, and every site I could find mentions June 12, 1970. For example : https://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/434667/Boris_Belousov

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The 1976 date appears to be a transcription error. Not only is the 1970 date more frequent in English literature, the two Russian language sources below (that appear to be independent) agree on a death date of June 12, 1970.

- [Great Chemists - BELOUSOV Boris Pavlovich](https://sites.google.com/site/velikiehimiki/belousov-boris-pavlovic)
- https://elementy.ru/nauchno-populyarnaya_biblioteka/434667/Boris_Belousov

Numerous other Russian language sources also give 1970 as the year of death, but I saw no reason to believe these were independent of the two above. I found no Russian language sources (of about 12) that listed 1976 as the year of death.

Comment: Thank you @Pieter Geerkens!